# select data from table and compare with dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, amazon-redshift

I have a dataframe like this

```
Name  age   city
John   31   London
Pierre 35   Paris
...
Kasparov 40 NYC
```

I would like to select data from redshift city table using sql where city are included in city of the dataframe

```
query = select * from city where ....
```

Can you help me to accomplish this query?

Thank you

Comment: are you using Python to query redshift?

Comment: yes I use python, jupyter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeril's answer is going to right direction but not complete. df.unique() result is not a string it's series. You need a string in your where clause

```
# create a string for cities to use in sql, the way sql expects the string
unique_cities = ','.join("'{0}'".format(c) for c in list(df['city'].unique()))

# output 
'London','Paris'

#sql query would be
query = f"select * from city where name in ({unique_cities})"
```

The code above is assuming you are using python 3.x

Please let me know if this solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
unique_cities = df['city'].unique()


# sql query
select * from city where name in unique_cities
```

Comment: Tahnk you, but there is a problem : 
ProgrammingError: column "unique_cities" does not exist in city